# Defining the CRS for memory layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, vector-layer, memory-layer

How can I define the CRS for a memory layer from the QGIS project settings?

```py
vpoi = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "vectpoi", "memory")
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(10,10)))
provider = vpoly.dataProvider()
...
```

And how can I define the CRS from another loaded layer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [QGIS API docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#details) state

> Memory data providerType (memory)
>
> The memory data provider is used to construct in memory data, for
> example scratch data or data generated from spatial operations such as
> contouring. There is no inherent persistent storage of the data. The
> data source uri is constructed. The url specifies the geometry type
> ("point", "linestring", "polygon",
> "multipoint","multilinestring","multipolygon"), optionally followed by
> url parameters as follows:
>
> **crs=definition Defines the coordinate reference system to use for the
> layer. definition is any string accepted by
> QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::createFromString()**
>
> index=yes Specifies
> that the layer will be constructed with a spatial index
>
> field=name:type(length,precision) Defines an attribute of the layer.
> Multiple field parameters can be added to the data provider
> definition. type is one of "integer", "double", "string".
>
> An example url is **"Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer&field=name:string(20)&index=yes"**

So I guess it's

```py
crs = votherpoly.crs().toWkt() # could also use .authid() instead of .toWkt()
vpoi = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + crs, "vectpoi", "memory")
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(10,10)))
provider = vpoly.dataProvider()
...
```

Comment: BTW. I also tested with QGIS 1.8 but that doesn't seem to work. e.g. vpoi = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:4326", "vectpoi", "memory") seems to be unrecognized. Although it is described here:  http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider.

Comment: Passing the CRS as WKT may not be safe if the definition includes an ampersand (e.g. EPSG:32161). It's a fairly niche case, but for this reason I'd say it is preferable to pass the .authid() instead. However, the memory provider doesn't seem to recognise authids from user defined projections (i.e. those with a USER: prefix).

Answer (score 8):

An alternate approach to that suggested by @MatthiasKuhn is to create the memory layer, then set the layer projection afterwards.

```py
vpoi = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:4326", "vectpoi", "memory") # create memory layer in WGS84
vpoi.setCrs(votherpoly.crs()) # change the coordinate reference system
```

If you don't specify any CRS initially (i.e. no `"crs="`) QGIS displays a warning to the user. This code creates a new memory layer using the WGS84 CRS, then changes the it to match the CRS from `votherpoly`. This avoids passing the CRS through the memory layer URI, which can have issues with some coordinate systems (such as those with an `'&'` in the name).

Answer (score 5):

This works well for me:

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer()
crs = vl.crs()
crs.createFromId(4326)
vl.setCrs(crs)
```

`crs()` method of the Vector layer returns [`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) (you can use alternatively class constructor. Like this:

```
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
```

`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` has method to create crs from Id (alternatively you can use methods for create CRS from PostGIS database, or some definitions of crs like wkt, or proj4).

On last line I set created SRS to my layer.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to provide a bit more detail than just code lines. Please explain your approach.