# Creating perpendicular line between two points inside polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point-in-polygon, polyline-creation, perpendicular

I'm looking for a solution in PyQGIS to create a cut line at the midpoint of another line that connects two points within a polygon. The objective is to cut the polygon into two parts.

[image]

In fact, this would be the alternative solution to the script below used to generate subdivisions in polygons with **more** than 2 points on it (based on cluster points and Voronoi). My problem is when I have two points inside one of these polygons.

The code was adapted from this [link](https://github.com/PedroVenancio/qgis_polygon_splitting).

```py
def split_polygon(poligonfeatures, numberofpoints, numberofparts):
    # Random points inside polygons
    alg_process = 'RandomPointsInsidePolygons'
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': poligonfeatures,
        'MIN_DISTANCE': None,
        'STRATEGY': 0,
        'VALUE': numberofpoints,
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons', alg_params)

    # K-means clustering
    alg_process = 'KmeansClustering'
    alg_params = {
        'CLUSTERS': numberofparts,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'CLUSTER_ID',
        'INPUT': outputs['RandomPointsInsidePolygons']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('native:kmeansclustering', alg_params)

    # Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)
    alg_process = 'ConcaveHullKnearestNeighbor'
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD': 'CLUSTER_ID',
        'INPUT': outputs['KmeansClustering']['OUTPUT'],
        'KNEIGHBORS': 3,
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:knearestconcavehull', alg_params)

    # Centroids
    alg_process = 'Centroids'
    alg_params = {
        'ALL_PARTS': False,
        'INPUT': outputs['ConcaveHullKnearestNeighbor']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('native:centroids', alg_params)

    # Voronoi polygons
    alg_process = 'VoronoiPolygons'
    alg_params = {
        'BUFFER': 100,
        'INPUT': outputs['Centroids']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons', alg_params)

    # Intersection
    alg_process = 'Intersection'
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': poligonfeatures,
        'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
        'OVERLAY': outputs['VoronoiPolygons']['OUTPUT'],
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.runAndLoadResults('native:intersection', alg_params)

split_polygon(layer, 50, 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this solution, none of the algorithms from the processing was used.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'polygon'* (five features) and a point layer called *'points_in_polygon'* (12 features) with its attribute tables, see the image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsVectorLayer

# layers' names
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points_in_polygon')[0]
polygon_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon')[0]

# crs for the output
output_crs = polygon_layer.crs().authid()

# creating a polyline layer for the output
polyline_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={output_crs}", "temp", "memory")
provider = polyline_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("id", QVariant.Int)])
polyline_layer.updateFields()

# looping over polygon and point features
polygons_with_points = {}

for polygon in polygon_layer.getFeatures():
    polygon_geom = polygon.geometry()
    points_in_polygon = []
    
    for point in point_layer.getFeatures():
        point_geom = point.geometry()
        if point_geom.within(polygon_geom):
            points_in_polygon.append(point_geom.asPoint())

    # only polygons with exactly two points inside are needed
    if len(points_in_polygon) == 2:
        polygons_with_points[polygon.id()] = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points_in_polygon)

# creating and editing polyline features
polyline_layer.startEditing()
for id, geom in polygons_with_points.items():
    feat = QgsFeature(polyline_layer.fields())
    feat.setAttribute("id", id)
    # getting line centroid as a rotation center
    centroid = geom.centroid().asPoint()
    # rotating line clockwise in 90 degrees
    geom.rotate(90, centroid)
    # extending line from start and end in 20 meters
    new_geom = geom.extendLine(0.0, float(20)).extendLine(float(20), 0.0)
    feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    polyline_layer.addFeature(feat)
polyline_layer.endEditCommand()
polyline_layer.commitChanges()

# adding output layer to the canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polyline_layer)
```

Change the names of the input layer in the first lines of code. Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: result]

*Note:* For line extension, probably a more robust technique should be used.

---

**References:**

- [Creating a Line feature in PyQGIS QGIS 3.x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340705/creating-a-line-feature-in-pyqgis-qgis-3-x)
- [How can I define the layer CRS for a memory layer in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70135/how-can-i-define-the-layer-crs-for-a-memory-layer-in-pyqgis)
- [Creating polygon from list of coordinates: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon has unexpected type list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241417/creating-polygon-from-list-of-coordinates-qgsgeometry-frompolygon-has-unexpecte)
- [What's the difference between QgsPoint, QgsPointXY and QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY()) in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377881/whats-the-difference-between-qgspoint-qgspointxy-and-qgsgeometry-frompointxyq)
- [Shortening line with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383992/shortening-line-with-pyqgis)
- [Extending only one end of line using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443175/extending-only-one-end-of-line-using-pyqgis)

Comment: It worked! Now I'm adapting this code for an iteration, as lines can sometimes cut more than a polygon (which is not desired). Keep on learning.

Answer (score 3):

If it is still necessary to use the code adapted from [QGISPolygonSplitting.py](https://github.com/PedroVenancio/qgis_polygon_splitting/blob/master/QGISPolygonSplitting.py), there are several suggestions to make it work:

- The holder for output is missing i.e. `outputs = {}` at the beginning
- parameter `numberofparts` must be greater than 2 i.e. `numberofparts > 2`, otherwise the [`QgsProcessingException`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingException.html) will raise when applying the ["qgis:voronoipolygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#voronoi-polygons):

  ```
  results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
  _core.QgsProcessingException: Input file should contain at least 3 points.
  Choose another file and try again.
  ```

So, after all your code will look as follows:

```py
def split_polygon(poligonfeatures, numberofpoints, numberofparts):

    outputs = {}

    # Random points inside polygons
    alg_process = 'RandomPointsInsidePolygons'
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': poligonfeatures,
        'MIN_DISTANCE': None,
        'STRATEGY': 0,
        'VALUE': numberofpoints,
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons', alg_params)

    # K-means clustering
    alg_process = 'KmeansClustering'
    alg_params = {
        'CLUSTERS': numberofparts,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'CLUSTER_ID',
        'INPUT': outputs['RandomPointsInsidePolygons']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('native:kmeansclustering', alg_params)

    # Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)
    alg_process = 'ConcaveHullKnearestNeighbor'
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD': 'CLUSTER_ID',
        'INPUT': outputs['KmeansClustering']['OUTPUT'],
        'KNEIGHBORS': 3,
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:knearestconcavehull', alg_params)

    # Centroids
    alg_process = 'Centroids'
    alg_params = {
        'ALL_PARTS': False,
        'INPUT': outputs['ConcaveHullKnearestNeighbor']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('native:centroids', alg_params)

    # Voronoi polygons
    alg_process = 'VoronoiPolygons'
    alg_params = {
        'BUFFER': 100,
        'INPUT': outputs['Centroids']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons', alg_params)

    # Intersection
    alg_process = 'Intersection'
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': poligonfeatures,
        'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
        'OVERLAY': outputs['VoronoiPolygons']['OUTPUT'],
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    outputs[alg_process] = processing.runAndLoadResults('native:intersection', alg_params)

    
split_polygon('polygon', 50, 3)
```

Comment: This code is still useful for cases with more than 3 points. Thank you for the tips.